# Roadmap for HTML5 features in WebKit for Android

Tags: android

I recently tried out the applicationCache / offline web apps on Android 2.1's WebKit and unfortunately it does not work exactly like on a webkit on the iPhone. I was wondering how I can easily see what features should be implemented and if there is something like a roadmap?

Does that information somewhere exist?